# Convert integer to color in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, colors

How to convert integer to color in WPF?
For example, I want to convert 16711935 to color.

How to do something like below in windows forms, in WPF?

```
myControl.Background = Color.FromArgb(myColorInt);
```

Comment: @GrantWinney WPF Color.FromArgb requires 4 parameters namely byte a, byte r, byte g, byte b.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the [`BitConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384066.aspx) Class to convert your value to a Byte Array, that way you do not need to import another namespace.

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(16711935);
this.Background = new SolidColorBrush( Color.FromArgb(bytes[3],bytes[2],bytes[1],bytes[0]));
```

Comment: Good way of doing it. Note however that if the integer contains argb values in that order - with alpha occupying the leftmost bits,  then you may need the parameters to Color.FromArgb the other way round... Color.FromArgb(bytes[3],bytes[2],bytes[1],bytes[0])

Comment: Good answer though as Simon says the bytes do need reversing if you are converting an int outputed by the System.Drawing.Color.ToArgb method.

Comment: @Simon You are right, just verified myself and edited the answer of Mark

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `System.Drawing.Color`, not `System.Windows.Media.Color`:

```
var myColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(16711935);
```

---

Ooookay, not sure this is very pretty, but you could convert from one `Color` class to the other, then use that in the `SolidColorBrush` ctor:

```
myControl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(
  System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(myColor.A,myColor.R,myColor.G,myColor.B));
```

Comment: I have edited the question. Above gives "Cannot implicitely convert "system.drawing.color" to "System.windows.Media.Brush" "error.

Comment: Good solution. For me at least, it is easier to follow what is going on in a glance, as opposed to using the accepted answer with the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

The System.Windows.Media.Color structure has similar methods but they have parameters of type Byte.  You can use the BitConverter class to convert between an array of Bytes and an Int32.