# Can't specify a SolidBrushColor

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I define a variable as follows:

```
x = Color.FromArgb(<some integer>)
```

and use it as follows when specifying a rectangle:

```
Dim Cell As New Shapes.Rectangle With
{
    .Fill = New SolidColorBrush(x),
    '......
}
```

However, this gives an error message:

> Value of type 'Color' cannot be converted to 'Color'

What is wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you are using `System.Windows.Media.Color` and not `System.Drawing.Color`

Comment: @JesseGood That would be `System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(Byte, Byte, Byte, Byte)` The OP is using `System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(Integer)`. I don't believe there is that overload in the Media namespace.

Comment: @Mary That doesn't matter. You can still not pass a System.Drawing.Color instance to the SolidColorBrush constructor.

Comment: @Clemens I was just pointing out that the OP will have to change the  parameters, as well as the namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different `Color` types.

- [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=net-5.0) (the one that you are using, GDI+)
- [`System.Windows.Media.Color`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.color?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) (the one WPF uses)

A [`SolidColorBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.-ctor?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Media_SolidColorBrush__ctor_System_Windows_Media_Color_) or brushes in general in WPF expect the latter type.

```
Public Sub New (color As Color)
```

Unfortunately, this type does not have an overload for a single `int`, which means you have to convert it and use this `FromArgb` method instead:

```
Public Shared Function FromArgb (a As Byte, r As Byte, g As Byte, b As Byte) As Color
```

You can use one of the approaches from [Convert integer to color in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21247974/6181599), like this one:

```
Dim bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(/* some integer */)
Dim color = Color.FromArgb(bytes(3), bytes(2), bytes(1), bytes(0))
Dim brush = New SolidColorBrush(color)
Dim Cell As New Shapes.Rectangle With
    .Fill = brush
}
```

Comment: I figured there were two Color classes based on the error message I got but did not know how to suss them out nor which was the best to use.  thatbuy put the puzzle pieces together.  Thanks.